# Implementing if-else in python dataframe using lambda when there are multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, lambda

I am trying to implement if-elif or if-else logic in python while working on a dataframe. I am struggling when working with more than one column.

sample data frame

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"one":[1,2,3,4,5],"two":[6,7,8,9,10], "name": 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'})
```

If my if-else logic is based on only one column - I know how to do it.

```
df['one'] = df["one"].apply(lambda x: x*10 if x<2 else (x**2 if x<4 else x+10))
```

But I want to modify column 'one' based on values of column 'two' - and I feel its going be something like this -

```
lambda x, y: x*100 if y>8 else (x*1 if y<8 else x**2)
```

But I am not sure how to specify the second column. I tried this way but obviously that's incorrect

```
df['one'] = df["one"]["two"].apply(lambda x, y: x*100 if y>8 else (x*1 if y<8 else x**2))
```

**Question 1 - what'd be the correct syntax for the above code ?**

**Question 2 - How to implement below logic using lambda ?**

```
if df['name'].isin(['a','b'])  df['one'] = 100 else df['one'] = df['two']
```

If I write something like x.isin(['a','b']) it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Apply across columns

Use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead of [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and specify `axis=1`:

```
df['one'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['one']*100 if row['two']>8 else \
                     (row['one']*1 if row['two']<8 else row['one']**2), axis=1)
```

Unreadable? Yes, I agree. Let's try again but this time rewrite as a named function.

#### Using a function

Note `lambda` is just an anonymous function. We can define a function explicitly and use it with `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
def calc(row):
    if row['two'] > 8:
        return row['one'] * 100
    elif row['two'] < 8:
        return row['one']
    else:
        return row['one']**2

df['one'] = df.apply(calc, axis=1)
```

Readable? Yes. But this isn't vectorised. We're looping through each row one at at at time. We might as well have used a list. Pandas isn't just for clever table formatting, you can use it for vectorised calculations using arrays in contiguous memory blocks. So let's try one more time.

#### Vectorised calculations

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['one'] = np.where(row['two'] > 8, row['one'] * 100,
                     np.where(row['two'] < 8, row['one'],
                              row['one']**2))
```

There we go. Readable *and* efficient. We have effectively vectorised our `if` / `else` statements. Does this mean that we are doing more calculations than necessary? Yes! But this is more than offset by the *way* in which we are performing the calculations, i.e. with well-defined blocks of memory rather than pointers. You will find an order of magnitude performance improvement.

#### Another example

Well, we can just use `numpy.where` again.

```
df['one'] = np.where(df['name'].isin(['a', 'b']), 100, df['two'])
```

Comment: Thanks for you very elaborate response. Even if lambda method is unreadable I just wanted to learn how it works. I was trying myself and figured out the 2nd method, but I couldn't make the df.isin() method work while using the function. I tried this -     if df['name'].isin(['a','b']):
        df['one'] = 10
        return df['one'] . But I am getting error 'str' object has no attribute isin.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
df.apply(lambda x: x["one"] + x["two"], axis=1)
```

but i don't think that such a long lambda as `lambda x: x["one"]*100 if x["two"]>8 else (x["one"]*1 if x["two"]<8 else x["one"]**2)` is very pythonic. apply takes any callback:

```
def my_callback(x):
    if x["two"] > 8:
        return x["one"]*100
    elif x["two"] < 8:
        return x["one"]
    else:
        return x["one"]**2

df.apply(my_callback, axis=1)
```